# gatsby staticquery in a react component not returing any data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

Just seem to have no luck what so ever with the static query within a react component. Seem to work fine on Pages but not working from components. Basically {data} is always coming as undefined. Tried allMarkdownRemark & markdownRemark with different Graphql code snippets. The query is returning correct data when querying directly via a graphql client but not through the react component.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
    import { Link } from "gatsby";
    import logo from "../../assets/images/logo.png";
    import footerMap from "../../assets/images/footer-map.png";

    export default () => {       
      return (
        <StaticQuery
          query={graphql`query FooterData {
      allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {componentKey: {eq: "Footer"}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              explore {
                footerlinks1
                footerlinks1Url
              }
              headoffice {
                Address
                HOAddress
                HONumber
              }
              services {
                footerlinks2
                footerlinks2Url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `}
     render={(data) => (
            <footer className="footer-area bg-color">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                   <h3>Explore</h3>

                      <ul className="footer-links-list">
                      {
                        data.allMarkdownRemarks.edges[0].node.frontmatter.explore.map(link => (
                        <li>
                            <Link to={link.footerlinks1Url}>{link.footerlinks1}</Link>          
                        </li>
                        ))}
                        </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </footer>
       )}
       />
    )};
                  




Error I am getting is below.
===========================
TypeError: Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined
render
C:/Users/HP/source/XXX/src/components/App/Footer.js:102
   99 | <div className="single-footer-widget pl-5">
  100 |   <h3>Explore</h3>
  101 | 
> 102 |   <ul className="footer-links-list">
  103 |   {
  104 |     data.allMarkdownRemarks.edges[0].node.frontmatter.explore.map(link => (
  105 |     <li>
View compiled
StaticQueryDataRenderer
C:/Users/HP/source/XXX/.cache/gatsby-browser-entry.js:37
  34 |   : combinedStaticQueryData[query] && combinedStaticQueryData[query].data
  35 | 
  36 | return (
> 37 |   <React.Fragment>
  38 |     {finalData && render(finalData)}
  39 |     {!finalData && <div>Loading (StaticQuery)</div>}
  40 |   </React.Fragment>
View compiled
▶ 19 stack frames were collapsed.
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your nested query object, you are using `allMarkdownRemarks` (note the last `S`) instead of `allMarkdownRemark` replace it by:

```
{data.allMarkdownRemark.edges[0].node.frontmatter.explore.map(link => (
  <li>
       <Link to={link.footerlinks1Url}>{link.footerlinks1}</Link>          
  </li>
))}
```

Comment: Yeah the typo happened when I copied code across and reduced the size of my post here. But the original code has no (s). The query returns null with allMarkdownRemark

Comment: And is totally working in your `localhost:8000/___graphql`?

Comment: Thanks @ferran, this fixed the issue 